# Changing variable name in foreach function in PowerShell

Tags: function, powershell, foreach

I have a script where a portion of it needs to run three different times, so I thought I'd try expand my limited PowerShell knowledge by calling the same code using a function rather than copying and pasting again and again, and making a longer-than-necessary script.

The code I want to re-use in a function:

```
$users = Get-Content users.txt
foreach ($user in $users){
    # Get some information from Exchange about the user
    $dn = (Get-MailboxStatistics -id $user).displayname
    $ic = (Get-MailboxStatistics -id $user).itemcount

    # Make a hash table where user=itemcount
    $firstrun += @{"$dn"="$ic"} # Each time the script runs, we
                                # need a different hash table

    # Kick off some Exchange maintenance on the user. (Removed
    # to keep the post shorter)
    # Item count should lower after a few seconds.
}
```

When the code repeats the second and third time, I want there to be a new hash table created ("secondrun" and "thirdrun"). My first problem is changing the name of the hash table name in the function each time - can this be done?

I also started to wonder if a hash table is even the right tool for the job or if there is something better? For a little more background, after I have the second hash table, I want to do a comparison:

```
foreach ($user in $users){
    $c1 = $firstrun.get_item($user)
    $c2 = $secondrun.get_item($user)

    # If the item count hasn't substantially dropped
    if ($c2 -ge $c1){
        # Do some different Exchange tasks on the user (removed
        # to keep the post shorter)
    }
}
```

And finally there'll be a third run which will simply create a third hash table (again, user=itemcount). I'll then output some kind of report to a text file using values in each of the hash tables.

I guess at this stage I have two main problems - having a changing variable name for the hash table in the function, and also I'm having difficulty maintaining the hash tables after the functions run - trying to declare them like global variables doesn't seem to work. I'm open for ideas on how any of this could be done better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand what you're saying, you are doing the following:

1. Populating a hash table that maps the set of users to their item count.
2. Doing something that prunes the items
3. Regenerate the hash table
4. Comparing the hash tables generated in steps 1 and 3; act on the list again.
5. Regenerate the hash table
6. Produce a report based on all three tables

As you can see from the above list, you really want to generate a function that produces the hash table and returns it:

```
function Get-UsersItemCount
{
    $ht = @{}
    $users = Get-Content users.txt
    foreach ($user in $users){
        # Get some information from Exchange about the user
        $dn = (Get-MailboxStatistics -id $user).displayname
        $ic = (Get-MailboxStatistics -id $user).itemcount

        # Make a hash table where user=itemcount
        $ht += @{"$dn"="$ic"}
    }

    $ht # Returns the hashtable
}
```

Now you can call this function three times:

```
$firstrun = Get-UsersItemCount

# Do first run stuff
$secondrun = Get-UsersItemCount

# Do second run stuff
$thirdrun = Get-UsersItemCount

# Generate your report
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just use one hash table, making the values an array, with one element for each pass:

```
$ht = @{}

$users = Get-Content users.txt
foreach ($user in $users){
    # Get some information from Exchange about the user
    $stats = Get-MailboxStatistics $user |
               select -expand itemcount
    $ht[user] += @($stats)}
}

# Kick off some Exchange maintenance on the user. (Removed to
# keep post shorter)
# Item count should lower after a few seconds.

foreach ($user in $users){
    # Get some information from Exchange about the user
    $stats = Get-MailboxStatistics $user |
               select -expand itemcount
    $ht[user] += @($stats)

    # If the item count hasn't substantially dropped
    if ($ht[$user][1] -ge $ht[$user][0])
        # Do some different Exchange tasks on the user (removed
        # to keep the post shorter)
}
```

Comment: Interesting - this also looks like valid alternative.  I've also just learnt about comparing elements in an array from you - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

What I would do if I were you?  I'll assume it doesn't matter what the name of the hash table is. If that's the case, you can grab the current date time and use that to name your hash table, like

```
$HashTblName = "HashTbl_$($(get-date).ToString("yyyyMMddhhmmssff"))"
```